# Add sound to keystrokes in iTerm2 / zsh

Tags: macos, audio, zsh, terminal.app, iterm2

I've been searching for quite a while now, but haven't found anything. I want to spice my terminal up a bit more than just colorizing it – I also want to add specific sounds to keystrokes, newlines etc.

Pretty much what you can to with Cathode, making it a bit futuristic and sci-fi to use.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't able to find a terminal specific solution for you, but you can enable keystroke sounds for the whole OS X like this:

1. In *System Preferences* under *Sound* -> *Sound Effects*, turn on `Play user interface sounds` .
2. In *System Preferences* under *Universal Access* -> *Keyboard*, turn on `Use click key sounds`, and move the acceptance delay slider all the way towards the “Short” end.